# Setting up beamer template

Tags: beamer

I would like to set up, in beamer in LaTeX, a template that I have from Power Point:

[image: Title page]

[image: General Slide template]

My code so far doesn't really reproduce the desired template:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useinnertheme{circles}
%\colorlet{beamer@blendedblue}{gray!40!black}
%\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\definecolor{ULgrey}{RGB}{128, 128, 128} % UL grey (primary)
\definecolor{ULred}{RGB}{218, 31, 40} % UL Red (secondary)
%
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=ULred} % itemize, enumerate, etc
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{bg=ULgrey} % TOC sections
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
% Override palette coloring with secondary
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=ULgrey,fg=ULred}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\title{TITLE}
\subtitle{SUBTITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\institute{University of Luxembourg}
\date{DATE}

%\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{logo.png}}

\begin{document}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% SLIDE 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usebackgroundtemplate{%             declare it
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=1, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{background.png}};
}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% SLIDE 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usebackgroundtemplate{}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{20mm}(.9\textwidth,-0.75cm)
\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{UniLU_logo.png}
\end{textblock*}}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% SLIDE 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Text

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the title page background rectangles? How can I make the round borders of the logo? How can I make the red little rectangle on the left side of the slides?

Comment: Look similar to [this](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uio-ifi-beamer/xmxqkppsfcrz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useinnertheme{circles}
%\colorlet{beamer@blendedblue}{gray!40!black}
%\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\definecolor{ULgrey}{RGB}{128, 128, 128} % UL grey (primary)
\definecolor{ULred}{RGB}{218, 31, 40} % UL Red (secondary)
%
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=ULred} % itemize, enumerate, etc
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{bg=ULgrey} % TOC sections
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=ULgrey,fg=white}
% Override palette coloring with secondary
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=ULgrey,fg=ULred}


\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,fill=ULgrey,text width=\paperwidth,text height=9ex,draw=ULgrey,opacity=0.5] (bgnode) at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north west)
{};
\fill[ULred] (bgnode.north west) rectangle ([xshift=1mm]bgnode.south west);
\node[anchor=west] (uni) at ([xshift=2ex]bgnode.west){%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\insertinstitute};
\matrix[anchor=west](listTAD) at ([xshift=3ex]uni.east) {%
\node{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle};  \\
\node{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\insertauthor}; \\ \node{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\insertdate};    \\
};
\node at ([xshift=-1.5ex]listTAD.west){\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\rule{0.5pt}{13mm}};
\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] (logoPos) at ([xshift=-2mm]current page.south east) {\phantom{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{logo.png}}};
\clip (logoPos.north west) |- (logoPos.south east) [rounded corners] -- (logoPos.north east) -- cycle;
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (logoPos) {\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{logo.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}



\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,fill=ULgrey,text width=\paperwidth,text height=7ex,draw=none] (bgnode) at (current page.north west)
{};
\node[above right=0.3ex and 2ex] (ntitle) at (bgnode.west){\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\insertframetitle};
\node[anchor=north west] at (ntitle.south west) {\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\insertframesubtitle};
\fill[ULred] ([yshift=-2mm]bgnode.north west) rectangle ([shift={(1.7mm,2mm)}]bgnode.south west);
\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] (logoPos) at ([xshift=-4mm]bgnode.south east) {\phantom{\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{logo.png}}};
\clip (logoPos.north west) |- (logoPos.south east) [rounded corners] -- (logoPos.north east) -- cycle;
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (logoPos) {\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{logo.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\title{TITLE}
\subtitle{SUBTITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\institute{University of Luxembourg}
\date{DATE}

%\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{logo.png}}

\begin{document}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% SLIDE 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usebackgroundtemplate{%             declare it
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=1, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{background.png}};
}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% SLIDE 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usebackgroundtemplate{}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
% SLIDE 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
Text

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: frame title]

[image: first page]

[image: second page]

Comment: Thank you! This works just fine. The only things that are not perfect (that I will try to solve) is that when there's a lot of content in the slide, it get superimposed on the grey slide title area. Also, I was not able to make the logo a bit smaller than the white rounded background. But it's not a biggie. I don't think they'll notice!

Comment: It was the first time that I make a beamer code of this kind. For make the logo a bit smaller in the frametitle, you should decrease both the values in scale. Now they are at 0.03.

Comment: for the superposition problem seem that if you put `\vbox{}\vskip+3ex%` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` can solve the problem.